# Vuejs using regular expersion in mount method with $emit

Tags: javascript, regex, vue.js, replace

with this below code i can observe to parent component to get data from that, this code work fine without any problem:

```js
    mounted() {
        this.$emit('caption', this.$el.innerText);
    }
```

now i want to use `replace` method to make `hashtag` from received texts, for example:

```js
    mounted() {
        this.$emit('caption', this.$el.innerText.replace('/#([\pL\pN_-]+)/u', 
               '<a href="https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/$1" target="_blank">#$1</a>'))
    }
```

this code with `replace` method is not correct and i'm not sure how can resolve that. how can i receive data from parent with `$emit` and use `replace` method to make a simple `hashtag`?

Comment: Instead of `'/#([\pL\pN_-]+)/u'`, you must use `/#([\p{L}\p{N}_-]+)/u`. Also, instead of `#$1`, you can just use a backreference to the whole match, `$&`,

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew how about `$1`? is this code correct? `this.$emit('caption', this.$el.innerText.replace(/#([\p{L}\p{N}_-]+)/u,
'<a href="https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/$1" target="_blank">$&</a>'))`

Comment: Yes, the `replace` looks correct, see [this JS demo](https://jsfiddle.net/fcb2e6s5/).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes that's correct, why it don't work with `v-html`? for example? `<p v-html="caption"></p>`  i don't have any link in this tag. like with `scape` html tags